# The char '0x0' after '' is not a valid XML character

Tags: java, axis

Estoy utilizando Axis 1.4, al obtener el response de un webservice desarrollado por un tercero me esta devolviendo el siguiente error:

> java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x0' after '' is not a
>   valid XML character

lo que sucede es que me esta devolviendo en el contenido del campo descripcion un String de 40 espacios en blanco.  El valor que trae descripcion es: "
                              "

El enconding que utilizo en utf-8

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta con el string que está retornando *(- el string que le está generando este error)*.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu XML contiene [caracteres unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) , específicamente  '0x0' se refiere a el [carácter Null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Este caracteres seguramente no es visible ya que esta dentro de la lista de "caracteres no imprimibles":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta ocurriendo un error al generar la respuesta, te sugiero revisar el Web Service, en lugar de entregar la información esta entregando valores null**.

Puedes revisar directamente el contenido de la respuesta en [esta página](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector), donde se mostraran en color rojo los caracteres unicode no imprimibles que estan causando el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Una forma de eliminar estos caracteres unicode en la respuesta es usando el siguiente REGEX:

```
String respuesta_limpia = response.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

Comment: Las clases la genero con WSDL2Java de Axis 1.4 y al webservice lo llamo:

`java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {auth, request});`

y el error lo obtengo dentro de las dependencia, lo cual no puedo agregar el codigo que recomendas